# Delete all user within a linked list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, file-pointer

I am new to C++, but may I know what are the possible ways to delete all nodes within a linked list (file). Given that, I have to input a file name and all the nodes within the file will be deleted. It seems that I'm unable to delete any files...

```
 void deleteF(filepointer &head, char *fileName)
    {
         filepointer deleteFile = head;
         while(deleteFile != NULL)
            {
                 if(strcmp(deleteFile-> nameofFile, fileName)==0 ){
                         delete deleteFile;
                   }
                 else{
                        cout<<"Fail deletion"<<endl;
                     }
             deleteFile = deleteFile -> nextFile;
            }
    }
```

Comment: If this is an excercise from a programming course, you should quit and learn C++ Standard Library instead.

Comment: So many errors... Code should not compile, listen your compiler.

Comment: It *does* delete the nodes, and leaves a list full of dangling pointers in its trail. Examining the contents of those nodes is undefined. You need to also unlink the nodes from the list.

Comment: How could I unlink the nodes from the list, any examples?

Answer (score 1):

`delete` is a keyword in C++. You cannot use it as an identifier for a function.

Give your function a different name.